# Google Analytics multiple tracking on a single web page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I recently get a partnership with a website, in order to put my Universal Analytics tracking code on a single web page. The website's owner has already one.

I've searched on Google Developers and Stack to find how to use multiple tracking codes. I built this code but I'm not sure whether it's OK, I don't want to interfere with his data. I just want to get common analytics data in my own account.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  //1- Create default tracker and mytracker
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto'); // His default tracker
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-50', 'auto', 'mytracker'); // My tracker

  //2- Get the pageview data of mytracker 
  ga(function(){

     var nonDefaultTracker = ga.getByName('mytracker');

     var mytrackerPageview = nonDefaultTracker.get('pageview'); 
     console.log(mytrackerPageview); 
  });   

  //3- Update mytracker pageview data
  ga('mytracker.set','pageview');

  //4- Send mytracker and default tracker pageview data
  ga('send','pageview'); 
  ga('mytracker.send','pageview'); 

</script>
```

Someone already did this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need step 2 and 3. The `get` method of the tracker returns the field specified in the argument, and since GA does not have a data field called `pageview` this will be `undefined` (which is the value you set as page path - you probably do not want this).

However pageview tracking will work fine without trying to retrieve values from the previous tracker. Unless you have set fields specifically set for a named tracker both will report the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! The owner tried my new code without steps 2 and 3 but I don't get any data in my analytics property. Indeed, Google Tag Assistant shows there is "No HTTP response detected".

Comment: It's really hard to say what happens without seeing the page. The code works when I copy it into the browser console (obviously one has to insert proper tracking ids), so the problem is caused by some condition that is not explicit in your question (but you might want to un-accept the answer if it did not solve your problem).

Comment: Trackings IDs are properly inserted. According to Tag Assitant, the owner's tracking ID works fine but mine doesn't work. Maybe I need to enable something in my property parameters ?

Comment: Did you check the realtime view in your account ? Tag Assistants error messages are not necessarily reliable.

Comment: I checked it but no data. Strange... Are you a google analytics specialist ?